# Multiple Select not able to post multuple values Form submit

Tags: mysql, symfony

Hi I have a Filed (multiple select using select2 plugin),name is, Template To , that will contain multiple , email addresses:

```
//My FormType Is:
->add('sendToEmailAddress', 'choice', array(
            'choices'   => array('LOCATION_OWNER' => 'LOCATION OWNER', 'ENQUIRER' => 'ENQUIRER','ENQUIRY_HANDLER' => 'ENQUIRY HANDLER'),
            'required'  => true,'data' => '','attr' => array('multiple'=>true,'class'=>'emalandSmsSendTo')
        ))

//My Twig File

{{ form_label(form.sendToEmailAddress, 'Send To Email', {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-md-3 control-label'}}) }}
        <div class="col-md-9">
            {{ form_widget(form.sendToEmailAddress) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.sendToEmailAddress) }}
        </div>

//My Entity Is:
 /**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="send_to_email_address")
 */
private $sendToEmailAddress;
/**
 * Set sendToEmailAddress
 *
 * @param Array $sendToEmailAddress     
 */
public function setSendToEmailAddress($sendToEmailAddress)
{
    $this->sendToEmailAddress = new ArrayCollection($sendToEmailAddress);
   // $this->sendToEmailAddress = $sendToEmailAddress;

    return $this;
   }

   /**
 * Get sendToEmailAddress
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
    public function getSendToEmailAddress()
    {
       return $this->sendToEmailAddress;
   }
```

I want to store multiple selected values into a single field "sendToEmailAddress" as serialized array. but while posting form this fields not able to post multiple filed it is only posting only one field.

Please guide what I am missing in this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your FormType, `'multiple'=>true` shouldn't be in the attr.

```
->add('sendToEmailAddress', 'choice', array(
            'choices'   => array('LOCATION_OWNER' => 'LOCATION OWNER', 'ENQUIRER' => 'ENQUIRER','ENQUIRY_HANDLER' => 'ENQUIRY HANDLER'),
            'required'  => true,
            'multiple'=>true,
            'data' => '',
            'attr' => array('class'=>'emalandSmsSendTo')
        ))
```

Comment: A best practive whould be to replace 'data' => '' with 'placeholder' => ''. I don't know if it affects something in Select, but in text field, it forces the value

Comment: Yes, I have resolved it thanks. now I am having another challange that I need to show select list as selected on edit Form. the values stores as serialized array in db, can you please assist me in this

Comment: Field Name: Email Addressess:

a:2:{i:0;s:8:"ENQUIRER";i:1;s:15:"ENQUIRY_HANDLER";}, On edit Form I need to display, selected default values which is selected by user at the time of save the data.is it possible?

Comment: That action is handled in the controller when you call handleRequest function. $form->handleRequest($entity);